# Ubuntu not seeing my main account?

Tags: login

So this morning i fired up Ubuntu like i normally would and it asked me to setup an account like i just installed it.
I went ahead since there was no other way forward and obviously this was an entirely new account but all my apps where installed.
i logged out and tried to login with my old account but clicking 'Not Listed' at the login screen.
THIS WORKED! i can login to my old account this way and all is well.

Could one of you kind people help me to get back to normal.
My account isn't on the User section of settings and it don't show up on the login screen